# Problems with Alienware Graphics Amplifie

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I am using Alienware 15r3 + Alienware Graphics Amplifier with RTX 2060 Super connected to external monitor. I have run into multiple problems. Ubuntu 21.10 installs with nouveau drivers as default. Before changing the drivers to official ones I have to change gdm to lightDM (if not my system becomes unbootable). I can’t install the 510 driver (from Softare and Updates) because it makes my system (again) unbootable. I can succesfuly install 470 nvidia drivers but my external display stays blank. I can see that GPU is detected in lspci but when I run nvidia-smi it says that no devices are detected. Does anyone know whar can cause the problem and how to solve it? I am frustrated because I have been fighting with it for 5 days and need my PC functioning ASAP. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's best to install the correct drivers during system installation. You must select/accept proprietary software and download updates while installing.  After the fact, you can run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the recommended driver.  However if you've already made several unsuccessful attempts using other methods, you may have done something that prevents you from getting this right.

Comment: My all attempts ended with reinstalling Ubuntu. Now I have to reinstall the system again. I’m not sure if the solution you suggested would work. From my knowledge Ubuntu comes with GDM as default Display Manager. As I mentioned I have to replace GDM with LightDM for my system to boot with internal display working.